# Storing Half Edge Data Structure objs using Meshlab?

Tags: opengl, 3d, 3d-modelling, meshlab

I'm currently using MeshLab for 3D modeling and was wondering how to convert a regular OBJ file, like

```
v X Y Z
f 1 2 3
```

to a file that has all the Half Edge Data Structure information.
I haven't found any digestible documentation online about how to do this with MeshLab and i feel like i'm missing a step somewhere. I thought it'd be as easy as exporting the OBJ file to another type, but I guess not. I need to extract info from it using OpenMesh and some functions but I can't even seem to be able to get a half edge data structure file to begin with. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Why not just [load the OBJ directly into OpenMesh](http://www.openmesh.org/media/Documentations/OpenMesh-Doc-Latest/a00062.html)?

Comment: I guess I could, i just thought there was a quick and easy way with Meshlab.

Comment: Also it seems that openmesh doesn't instantly convert triangulated mesh obj files into half edge information. I'd have to load it in and use the auxilary functions in openmesh to make the information (edge list, vertex arrays, etc). Which is bad for me because i didn't want to spend so much time learning to code the actual conversion, i just honestly figured there was a quicker way to just kind of plug in a file and receive the info for that specific mesh.